# PyQT5 OpenGL zoom

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyqt, pyqt5

So I wanted to make a zoom functionality in PyQT. And from answer [8.040](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm) I implemented it as such:

```
class GLWindow(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.object = 0
        self.zoomFactor = 1.0

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.WheelFocus)
        self.lastPos = QPoint()
```

and

```
def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glOrtho(-2 * self.zoomFactor, +2 * self.zoomFactor, +2 * self.zoomFactor, -2 * self.zoomFactor, 4.0, 15.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
```

Now at the start of the program if I change the `self.zoomFactor` to let's say 2.0, it has the desired effect of a zoom, but I can't seem to resize it while running.

```
def wheelEvent(self, event):
    """http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html"""
    scroll = event.angleDelta()
    if scroll.y() > 0:  # up
        self.zoomFactor += 0.1
        self.resizeGL(self.width(), self.height())
        self.update()
        pass
    else:  # down
        pass
```

The above code is how I tried it already, without the desired effect. It catches the upwards zoom and calls the `resizeGL` function, but won't zoom in/out.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. It does work. The `resizeGL` only updates when resizing the window, so we have to use it in another method.

Comment: The method I use it in now is `paintGL`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone else:

```
def paintGL(self, coordinates=None):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glPushMatrix()

    glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -50.0)
    glScale(0.1 * self.zoomFactor, 0.1 * self.zoomFactor, 0.1 * self.zoomFactor)
    glRotate(self.rotX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glRotate(self.rotY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glRotate(self.rotZ, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glTranslate(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertVBO)

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, len(self.edges), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.edges)

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    glPopMatrix()

def wheelEvent(self, event):
    scroll = event.angleDelta()
    if scroll.y() > 0:
        self.zoomFactor += 0.1
        self.update()
    else:
        self.zoomFactor -= 0.1
        self.update()

def initializeGL(self):
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    self.initGeometry()

    self.rotX = 0.0
    self.rotY = 0.0
    self.rotZ = 0.0

    self.zoomFactor = 1.0
```

To zoom in/zoom out you must call glScale() function before render shape instead resizeGL()